# Is There a way to recover a severely corrupted EXCEL FILE?

Tags: excel

I'm currently working on my data using Ms.Excel.

But suddenly the file that I'm working in was broken. when I tried to open it again I get error where it contain `"ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ"` (See Picture).
[Screenshoot Corrupted Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK5RQ.jpg)

The data was not really big, it's only arround 130KB. Besides, Autorecovery Mode was Turned On every 10 minutes. But I don't know How To use it.

I tried to solve the problem many times using below method:

1. First, I tried to check the "Ignore .... " in Excel Option.
2. Second, I tried Open and Repair the file, but still can't open it.
3. Third, I tried to use a third party, Using 2 Software (Stellar Phoenix Excel Repair And Recovery Tools For Excel). but Both not Working.

So I wonder if anyone can help me to get my data back? is there any way to recover the file? or is there a way to get the data within the file?

Comment: What was the file extension?

Comment: You could possibly use something like Programmers File Editor and do a find/replace for those "odd" characters, then see what is left... But make a copy first... Which would have been a good idea from the start.

Comment: xlsx @Bathsheba.

Comment: @RamondeVries: Good detective work! An `xlsx` is just a `zip` file. So rename your file to have a `zip` extension and inspect the contents. That will allow you to view and extract the data.

Comment: Which application are you using to open the file?

Comment: @Bathseba    Xlsx, I Tried to change the extension to  ".xls" too but still nothing good came. and btw I already tried to zip it before, it said the file was damaged.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Currently In the screenshot was WPS Spreadsheet, cuz when I tried it using Ms.excel, it won't open with only a messagebox appear "The file Extention was not corret or the file may be corrupted". Somethng along this line.

Comment: fyi, the original file was using MS.Excel

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the suggestion, I see maybe this one will work. I hope so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestion you gave me, From the last comment I tried to get and extract the data using Programmer editor and using VBA, but both not give a good result, basically when you tried to extract the data when the file is corrupted it only get a unique character.

So here is my solution, since i'm using windows, I tried to Reinstall my Ms.Office and recover my Excel file on mac, and boom the magic worked.

Once again, thanks for your help.